# Ads by LaSuperba showing on every browser

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, malware

A few days ago an ad "Powered by LaSuperba" is showing on every broser of my Ubuntu 14.04. My main browser is google-chrome, but it happens on Firefox and Opera aswell.
I noticed that it doesn't happen on incognito mode, but even removing EVERY extension from Chrome didn't do the trick.

- Update
  I've also tried removing every browser preference file, reinstaled the SO keeping the /home partition and the problem is still there. So I think it hides somewhere in my home dir.

It looks like that this ads overlays something on the browser using SWF. Some sites like feedly even stop working because of this "overlay".

Any ideas?

Comment: Clear your cookies. And don't remove all add-ons. You might want to keep an adblocker around.

Comment: At the bottom of [this page](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/ads-by-lasuperba-removal/), after much Windows-oriented information, are instructions for cleaning out Google Chrome and Firefox. Did you try these?

Comment: @mark: Since it happens on multiple browsers, "fixing" 1 browser cannot fix the problem. You could look at `/etc/resolv.conf` to see where your DNS comes from, use `tracepath` (`sudo apt-get install tracepath`) to see where your connections go, `wireshark` to watch the connections, check `/etc/hosts` for strangeness. You could use a command-line browser (`lynx`, `links`) to expose more info. Any idea who/what "LaSuperba" is? ISP? Porn site? Your Government? J. Random Hacker?

Comment: @waltinator I don't see anything unusual on resolv.conf or hosts. I've tried removing the ~/ .config/google-chrome and ~/.config/opera but it didn't do the trick. I'll try cleaning the cookies.
I don't really know what la superba is, looks like a malware for ads. Now I have ads popping up on every site that I open and sometimes new tabs open on their own with ads.

Comment: There was (on my computer at home, 6 1/2 hours away) a Firefox extension to show all sites connected to, but its name slips my mind. You could use `wireshark` to capture all TCP/IP packets in and out, and inspect them. `man wireshark`

Comment: It's best to NOT make random changes to your system. First, figure out what is causing the problem, and make the needed change to fix it.

Comment: Read `man wireshark`. Reread it. Shutdown your browsers, and stop all internet activity (to make the packet capture less noisy). Re-reread `man wireshark`. Start `wireshark`, capturing all TCP/IP packets. Start 1 browser, let it run until the "La Superba" shows up. Tell `wireshark` to stop capturing packets. If you can't decode what `wireshark` is showing, use `wireshark` to save the captured packets and post the `.pcap` file to a file sharing site. Post the link here, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @waltinator I've been wanting to test other distros for a while, so I installed OpenSuSe keeping my /home partition. The same "la superba" is still there

Comment: @waltinator I'm tracking with wireshark and I think I'm getting somewhere: http://bit.ly/1KTyf0a

Answer (score 0):

My roommate caught the same malware days ago and he found [this post](http://www.fastremovevirus.com/how-to-get-rid-of-ads-by-lasuperba-in-detailed-steps.html) useful. I suppose it can give you some reference as well. You need to check files to clean ads.